# hadoop mapper/reducer in python

Tags: python, hadoop, reducers

I want to extract data from 3 databases movies.dat, users.dat and ratings.dat. To identify a movie with highest value of average males rating minus average females rating and another movie with highest value of average females rating minus average males rating. Simply one movie which is most highly rated by men but not by women, and a movie most highly rate by women but not by men. I have written the code for the mapper.py and want to reduce the data, need some help with the logic and code. 
Here is my mapper.py

```
for line in sys.stdin:
line=line.strip()  
lst = line.split("::")
if len(lst) == 4:
userID=lst[0]
        movieID=lst[1]
        rating=lst[2]
elif len(lst)==5:  
userID=lst[0]  
        gender=lst[1]
else:
movieID=lst[0]
print '%s, %s, %s'%(movieID,rating,gender)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should be your mapper if there are 3 datasets.

```
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:


line=line.strip()  
lst = line.split("::")
if len(lst) == 5:
    user=lst[0]  
    gender=lst[1]
print '%s^%s^%s^%s^%s'%(user,gender,0,0,0)
elif len(lst)==4:
user=lst[0]
    movie=lst[1]
    rating=lst[2]
    print '%s^%s^%s^%s^%s'%(user,0,movie,rating,0)
else:
movie=lst[0]
title=lst[1]
print '%s^%s^%s^%s^%s'%(0,0,movie,0,title)
```